# How to increase speed of code in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a portion of code that is called an enormous amount of times. How can I speed it up?

```
#define SUM_(p0, p1, p2, p3, offset) 
((p0)[offset] - (p1)[offset] - (p2)[offset] + (p3)[offset]) 

inline int Calc::compute( int offset ) const

{
int b = SUM( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset ); 
int a1 = SUM(...);
int a2 = SUM(...);
....
return (uchar)(((a1 >= b) << 7) |       
               ((a2 >= b) << 6) |       
               ((a3 >= b) << 5) |       
               ((a4 >= b) << 4) |       
               ((a5 >= b) << 3) |       
               ((a6 >= b) << 2) |       
               ((a7 >= b) << 1) |       
                (a8 >= b));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: First do some profiling with real world data to find out if this is really a bottleneck. Second, could you go into more detail what "an enormous amount of times" means? Third, what problem are you really trying to solve. Perhaps there's a solution where you don't need to call this code "an enormous amount of times".

Comment: Are you running the release build? In processing medical images, I have seen cases where a Visual Studio debug build was 100 times slower than a release build.

Comment: I did a profiling on the program and yes this is the bottleneck. This is used for training and it takes around 30 million images and on each image the above code is done around 10 million times to get some features.
Yes I am running in release.

Comment: any specific portion of this function which is the bottleneck?

Comment: You may want to dump the assembly code for this and see if optimizing that helps.

Comment: @drescherjm
I am sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean to dump the assembly code?

Comment: Have the compiler generate an asm listing when it compiles the .cpp file containing this function. There is a compile switch for that and you can do it for individual files.

Comment: What type is `p`? If it's an iterator then it might be slow if iterators are checked by default. Try `#define _SECURE_SCL = 0` before including anything.

Comment: Does some calculations between a1, a2, .. be factorized ?

Comment: It is a bad idea to stuff the code with `...`, you are not telling us all we need to know.

Comment: -1 for asking us to optimize code which you haven't shown in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 3 possible opportunities here:

- Pack your p0, p1, p2 and p3 data contiguously in memory (so basically contiguously in an array) in order to prevent cache misses:

  ```
  #define SUM_(array, offset) 
  (array[offset] - array[offset + 1] - array[offset + 2] + array[offset + 3]) 

  ....
  //make sure pArray contains all the p0, p1, ... values.
  int a1 = SUM(pArray, offset);
  ```
- replace the bitshift operator with an if structure that or's togethers static literals if (a1 >=b) and so on. The values are going to be static everytime anyway:

  ```
  uint8_t bitmask = 0;
  if(a1 >= b)
     bitmask |= 0x80;
  if(a2 >= b)
     bitmask |= 0x40;
  ...
  ```
- Try to make sure that SIMD instructions are being used. This involves dumping the assembly and see if these kind of instructions are being generated.

EDIT: Reaction on the comment below:

In order to prevent cache misses, everything revolves around accessing your data in a predictable manner. A problem with your original code is that you resolve the offset with your p-variables.

So you have something like:

```
    int b  = SUM( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], _offset ); 
    int a1 = SUM( p[0], p[1], p[4], p[5],  _offset ); 
    int a2 = SUM( p[1], p[2], p[5], p[6],  _offset );
```

You could create an array which contains these values in the order you use them.

So I'd try to create an array that looks like this at a certain offset:

```
    p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], p[0], p[1], p[4], p[5], p[1], p[2], p[5], p[6]
```

And now you can define your sum function like this:

```
    #define SUM_(array, offset, calculationOffset) 
    (array[offset + calculationOffset * 4] - array[offset + calculationOffset * 4 + 1]
    - array[offset + calculationOffset * 4 + 2] + array[offset + calculationOffset * 4 + 3])
```

Your calls can be transformed into this:

```
    int b  = SUM(pArray, offset, 0);
    int a1 = SUM(pArray, offset, 1);
    int a2 = SUM(pArray, offset, 2);
```

There's only one problem with this: if you have to create the array and copy all the data every function call, this might remove any benefit of what we did, but you may be able to construct this kind of array before using this function and pass it as an argument.

Comment: For the first solution, how can I do it if I have something like:

    int b = SUM( p[5], p[6], p[9], p[10], offset );
    int a1 = SUM( p[0], p[1], p[4], p[5], _offset );
    int a2 = SUM( p[1], p[2], p[5], p[6], _offset );

The second solution I will try it now and decide afterwards.
The third solution I have no idea how to do that. If you can give me a link or somewhere to learn I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure if the second solution helps. It all depends on the compiler (if it's smart enough to detect that these bitshift calculations always give the same result). For the first solution, I'm going to send a comment in a little while, after I've formulated a proper response.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly to your additional question. (Formatting in comments unfortunately doesn't work as well)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will try it and see the results. It will be a lot to change in the code. If I have any other questions I will ask.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome. But just a piece of advise: make sure you document the layout of this array and the meaning of these calculations extensively. I can imagine the code becoming a lot more obscure because of these changes for the outsider. (and even yourself in a few years).

Good luck!

Comment: Apparently I was wrong about the SIMD instructions. Using them requires you to restructure your calculations to do calculations over whole arrays. I haven't really used them myself yet, so I'd advise you to do the research yourself. But I know they can be used to improve the performance in this case even further. But it doesn't change the fact that reducing cache misses will probably improve your performance the most.

Answer (score 0):

There's still the possibility to change/improve the algorithm itself. We cannot help you with this unless the algorithm you use is known (I mean the algorithm which uses the code you have shown).

If there are any known properties of the variables used and their values, this could give room for improvement.

I don't know whether the cast to `uchar` could impact performance. Why do you need this? I think this should be changed, since you are adding `int` and returning `int`. But you'd have to neasure performance to see if for example using `& 0xff` would give better performance.

Also, you should try the difference it makes when you replace the bit-oring-operators ("|") by a simple addition (should work the same in this case because each summand has a single unique bit set to 1).

Then try the effect of altering `(a1 >= b) << 7)` to `(a1 >= b) ? 128 : 0)` etc.

All of the above might or might not effect performance, and you have to measure the effect with the compiler you use.

But most important: if your problem with analyzing all these images is the total amount of time, you should look into processing different images at the same time (if you are on a multiprocessor machine with sufficient RAM). You have several options:

1. parallizing the code that processes a single image (using something like [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP))
2. Use one thread per image (IMHO much easier and I'd expect better overall throughput than 1.)
3. Move the concurrency to where your start your program (ie. a script).

Comment: I have done already the paralyzing. Now it takes around 4 hours to train a detector down from 28 hours.
Before I had  (a1>= b) ? 128 : 0 , and the results in both case are the same.